# python - How to parse numbers around a specific word/phrase

Tags: python

Suppose that I have a text like this:

`Our favorite numbers are 5, 6, and 7, but his favorite number is 0. Also, this text contains 2 sentences.`

Let's say I'd like to get favorite numbers only in this text, for instance. I won't be able to know if there's a favorite number in this text, unless the phrase `favorite number` is present. So I'm basically trying to parse numbers around the phrase `favorite number` (or `favorite numbers`). The expected result should be something like this:

```py
['5', '6', '7', '0']
```

I tried using regex for that but I've failed so far. What's the most logical way to do this?

Edit: After reading @LouiseDavies's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266685/python-how-to-parse-numbers-around-a-specific-word-phrase/47268575#comment81484054_47266685), I'll add another example below:

`Alice has 2 favorite numbers: 11 and 12. Bob has 10 favorite numbers: 0, 100, 1264, 598, 78496, 33546, 1028896, 23, 48, 6.`

So in this example, my output should be something like this (the order doesn't matter):

```
['11', '12', '0', '100', '1264', '598', '78496', '33546', '1028896', '23', '48', '6']
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and in what way(s) it "failed".

Comment: Is there any restriction on what types of phrases could pop up? For example, the problem is much harder if a sentence like `Alice has 2 favourite numbers: 6 and 7` is possible

Comment: @ScottHunter I basically tried bunch of regex patterns, and they were mostly basic ones so I didn't really want to write a much longer question by putting those patterns as well.

Comment: @LouiseDavies That really is a great question, I totally forgot about it. In your example, I'd only need `6` and `7`, not `2`. I'll edit my post by adding your question in a slightly different version.

Comment: This question is still incredibly difficult if there are no restrictions on what the phrase could be structured like: for example, most of the regex answers would fail in my first example, and although @Ajax's answer avoids the trap of my previous example, the sentence `7 is my favourite number` would fool that answer. One can do this infinitely, as I can pretty much always construct a new sentence (e.g. `if asked what my top 3 favourite numbers were, I think I'd have to say 7, 8 and 9`. This is why natural language processing is hard if you don't put at least some restriction on the input

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show any code so I won't write a complete solution.

You could split at `.`, filter the sentences that have `"favourite number"` and extract the numbers from those sentences. You shouldn't try to write a regex for the whole sentence.

Here's a start:

```
text = "Our favorite numbers are 5, 6, and 7, but his favorite number is 0. Also, this text contains 2 sentences."

import re
pattern = re.compile("favou?rite numbers?", re.I)

print([sentence for sentence in text.split('.') if pattern.search(sentence)])
# ['Our favorite numbers are 5, 6, and 7, but his favorite number is 0']
```

Now that you have the list of interesting sentences, you're one list comprehension and one `re.findall('d+')` away from a complete solution.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment

Comment: @Adirio: Why exactly? OP didn't show any code. Writing a working solution from my answer is straightforward.

Comment: A single sentence giving advice on how to implement doesn't look like an answer to me.

Comment: There are 3 concrete steps in this sentence. Which one don't you understand?

Comment: I understood all, but I still think that it fits better a comment that an answer. It may just be my opinion. The downvote is not mine, by the way.

Comment: @Adirio: Updated. I won't write a more complete answer as long as OP doesn't show more effort

Comment: This answer does not output desired numbers for OP, it's just returns a string contain numbers.

Comment: @Arman: See the first sentence. It's not encouraged to write complete solutions to incomplete questions.

Comment: if question is incomplete then don't write an incomplete answer , just ask OP to complete his question , this answer won't help OP and others.

Comment: @Arman: ScottHunter already asked for clarification. My approach is much simpler than trying to get the number in one single step. See Ajax1234's answer to see what I mean. No wonder OP would have troubles writing such a regex.

Comment: @EricDuminil Thank you for your answer, it worked for my original question. I edited it again, adding a slightly different one. I'd appreciate if you could take a look at it as well.

Also, could you please explain that in what way(s) my question is (or was) incomplete? I'm still a newbie here in stackoverflow, so I really don't what were you expecting as a "complete" question.

Comment: @emreorta: "Incomplete" means that you should show us the code you tried, along with the corresponding error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re
import itertools
s = 'Our favorite numbers are 5, 6, and 7, but his favorite number is 0. Also, this text contains 2 sentences.'

numbers = re.findall('(?<= favorite number is)[,\s\d]+|(?<=favorite numbers are)[,\s\dand]+', s)
final_numbers = list(itertools.chain(*[re.findall('\d+', i) for i in numbers]))
```

Output:

```
['5', '6', '7', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in my phone so I can't check my code, in my home I will check it.

```
text = "Our favorite numbers are 5, 6, and 7, but his favorite number is 0. Also, this text contains 2 sentences."
sentences = text.split('.')
numbers = set()
for sentence in sentences:
    if "favorite number" in sentence:
        numbers = numbers.union(set(sentence))
numbers = list(numbers.difference(set([*[chr(n) for n in range(32,48)],*[chr(n) for n in range(58,168)]])))
numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers]
print(numbers)
```

Another way could be:

```
text = "Our favorite numbers are 5, 6, and 7, but his favorite number is 0. Also, this text contains 2 sentences."
sentences = text.split('.')
numbers = []
for sentence in sentences:
    if "favorite number" in sentence:
        for character in sentence:
            try:
                number.append(int(character))
            except ValueError:
                pass
print(numbers)
```

Using `timeit.timeit` and checking the function `100000` times (without the `print()`) it give me `3.614777436797135` for the first way and `12.934136042429973` for the second way. So the first isn't exactly ordered but it's `3.57` times faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit longer than the other answers, but the state machine approach might turn out more maintainable if your needs change.

```
import re

text = """
Our favorite numbers are 5, 6, and 7, but his favorite number is 0. Also, this text contains 2 sentences.
"""

r = re.compile(r"(\d+|[a-zA-Z ]+)")

faves = False
lst = []

while True:
    s = r.search(text)
    if s is None:
        break
    x = s.group(1).strip()
    if x:
        if x == 'and':
            pass
        elif re.search(r'favou?rite numbers?', x):
            faves = True
        elif re.match(r"^\d+$", x) and faves:
            lst.append(x)
        else:
            faves = False
    text = text[s.end():]

print lst
```